# Why is Bahamut the Grand Master of Flowers in the new MTG set?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, magic-the-gathering

As I understand, *'Grand Master of Flowers'* is a title given to the leader of the Monastery of the Yellow Rose, What relationship does it have to Bahamut?

The monastery appears to worship a different deity, and Bahamut is not really a god of monks. Why did Wizards print Bahamut as this monk?

[image]

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/wizards_Magic/status/1395418187747893252

Comment: Probably an AD&D reference.  The (there can be only one) 17th-level monk is "The Grand Master of Flowers" regardless of alignment.  (Unlike 16th level, which had one master per alignment.)

Comment: https://mobile.twitter.com/StevenMace16/status/1412060230071033857 - Looks like you'll have to wait and see. Possibly a tie-in with an upcoming book

Comment: @Valorum I know he is not a planeswalker, both parts I am asking exist in Forgotten Realms without MTG.

Comment: @DavidW as I said in the question https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Grandmaster_of_Flowers is a specific position in Forgotten Realms not just a monk level

Comment: @Andrey Nowhere in your question is there a reference to *Forgotten Realms*.  If that is important to your question (as your comments seem to suggest) then you really need to add that.  Note also that the Monk class predates *Forgotten Realms*.

Comment: @DavidW The MTG set the card comes from is titled *Adventures in the Forgotten Realms*.  Which is important information the OP left out, but that is probably where the reference to the *Forgotten Realms* comes from.

Comment: Added the tag for Forgotten Realms. Yeah, the MTG set specific to that DND setting. I just of forgot everyone might not know that

Comment: Seventh and last, are *you* going to tell the First Dragon that he can't be a monk?

Comment: @Shadur This is not about being a monk. This is more like off hand finding out Thor is the new Orthodox Pope

Answer (score 5):

### Possibly a hint towards the future?

Bahamut is known to disguise himself as a human surrounded by seven canaries in order to advance good causes. It would appear he is doing that in his card. This is especially apparent in his alternate art, which gives more inhuman eyes.

[image]

I don't know why specifically they chose to combine these two previously unrelated elements of the lore. However, Bahamut is a lawful-good god and the Monastery is a lawful-good organization, so it's not the biggest jump that Bahamut would find them interesting. I've also seen speculation that this is a hint towards an upcoming development based on the [Way of the Ascendant Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/subclasses/way-of-the-ascendant-dragon-ua) monks coming to D&D soon.

Comment: The canaries were actually Gold Dragons, I think.

Comment: What two elements are you referring to?  Disguising himself as a human with canaries and ???

Comment: @lupus Bahamut and the monastery